# How to use Matcher.quoteReplacement with appendTail for strings having $ as literal

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like

> Hello $1 abc $1 $2 $3
>      Hello $1 abc $1 $2 $3
>      Hello $1 abc $1 $2 $3

If i want to search for **"Hello .*? abc"** and replace it with something,
i was using **matcher.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(s));** But, how do i use the same with appendTail() method?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE+Pattern.DOTALL );
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
String sub;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while(m.find()){
    String s = m.group();   
    s = s.replaceAll(replaceTagpattern, replaceWithTagpattern);
    m.appendReplacement(sb, Matcher.quoteReplacement(s));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
```

Edit:

Expected output:

> something $1 $2 $3
>      something $1 $2 $3
>      something $1 $2 $3

Comment: Escape the `$` by preceding it with a backslash. i.e. `\$`. In Java you would have to escape the backslash as well though, so it would be `\\$`.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: Yeah but, i don't want to edit the original content.

Comment: `appendTail` would simply append the last " $1 $2 $3".